# Object deleted because of move constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-constructor

I am trying to create a function running in a dedicated thread which
reads from a serial port. But I have trouble passing the connection
to the thread. I reduced my code to the following example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

template <typename Port>
void serial_read( Port& port) {}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service serial_io;
  boost::asio::serial_port port( serial_io );
  port.open( "/dev/ttyUSB0" );

  std::thread s( serial_read<boost::asio::serial_port>, port );
  return 0;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple:128:25: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>::basic_serial_port(const boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:25:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp:47:7: note: ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>::basic_serial_port(const boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
```

The error message is quite clear. I'm attempting to use an object
which is not existent because it has been deleted due to the
declaration of a move constructor. But I still don't understand
what's going on here and how to do it correctly. Can someone
enlighten me?

Comment: The error message doesn't say what you think it's saying. It's saying that the copy-constructor has been marked as _deleted_, i.e. there is no copy-constructor. The object itself is _not_ deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading the error correctly. It's is telling you that the *copy constructor* of `boost::asio::basic_serial_port` is `delete`d. This means the copy constructor cannot be used. It has nothing to do with objects being deleted. The reason the copy constructor is `delete`d is because a move constructor is defined.

If you really need to pass a reference to `serial_read`, you'll need to wrap your `port` object in a `reference_wrapper`:

```
std::thread s( serial_read<boost::asio::serial_port>, std::ref(port) );
```

However, if you don't to keep a hold of `port` and use it for anything else (such as passing the same `port` object to other threads), you should `std::move` your `port` object into the thread:

```
std::thread s( serial_read<boost::asio::serial_port>, std::move(port) );
```

This requires also changing the definition of `serial_read` to take `Port` by value:

```
template <typename Port>
void serial_read( Port port) {}
```

Comment: This throws a different error: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>’`

Comment: @Marco: The question is whether you need that function to receive a *reference* to the object or it could just get its own. If you need a reference you must use a reference wrapper, if it can use its own (you don't care about what happens with `port` in `main`) then change the signature of the `serial_read` to take the argument by value. (untested, mileage *will* vary)

Comment: @Marco: you need the same `Port` object to be shared by different threads? If you need it to be shared by multiple threads you cannot pass it by value as it will *move* the contents out of the original object. Also note that if you really the object is shared by multiple threads you will probably need to add synchronization (don't know what the boost::asio thread-safety guarantees are), which in turn means that you are probably better off creating a type that encloses the port and the synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: I noticed that, too. Passing by value fails. Now I'm passing by reference and it works fine so far. But I will definitely read about those synchronisation and thread-safety topics.

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix (I believe, untested) is to use a reference wrapper (if you really need to maintain both the object in `main` and in the thread):

```
std::thread s(&serial_read<boost::asio::serial_port>,std::ref(port));
```

The problem is that `std::thread` (as `std::bind` will create a functor with a copy of the arguments) that will later be used (with no argument). Basically the call above is similar to:

```
std::thread( std::bind(&serial_read<boost::asio::serial_port>,std::ref(port)) );
```

In the *bound* object a copy of each one of the arguments is stored, which requires the arguments to be copy constructible. The use of the reference wrapper allows for the copy (the wrapper is copied, the original object is not).

Another alternative, if you don't need to maintain the `port` object valid in `main` is to move from it, so that instead of *copying* into the *bound* object you allow the implementation to *move* from the object in `main`.

Comment: I think both of our solutions will work. One is a reference, one is not.

Comment: This solution seems to work. I will check if it works as part of the bigger project as well.